# Extract images from recovered files

Tags: photography, data-recovery

I have recovered  lots of image files from a dying hard drive. Some of them converted to good jpeg files, but some converted to "tif" files with various sizes. Files that are big (30-100mb) can be opened in photoshop or preview, but photos like on the screenshot below can't be opened in any application I have tried. All files that can't be opened are around 800kb-2mb with big resolution so clearly files are corrupted, maybe this is a preview of a raw file or something. So given that macos shows small preview (so there is at least SOME information there) - is there any way to extract anything from that files? I have tried Foremost (not finding anything including in big files that are open in preview), BinWalk (extracts tif data but it is same as original file - shows preview but black in Preview app) and ImageMagick convert without any luck. Looking for anything I can try on any system.

[image]

Comment: What camera are they from? There's a possibility that they are RAW files misinterpreted as .tif [though 2.5MB is small for a RAW 24mpx image]& what you're finding with your exploratory work is the embedded jpg, not the full RAW file. It *might* be as simple as renaming them to .NEF or CR2 etc

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/ImpulseAdventure/JPEGsnoop

This app helped me. Weirdly enough it looks like all images contain a big size image (compressed I guess but not heavily). The app is Windows only but works with crossover on a mac.